# I can't find CRYPTO_LOCK in openssl/crypto.h

Tags: c, iphone, linux, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

I try to install libimobliedevice package, so I install several packages including OpenSSL newest version in formal site of OpenSSL (www.openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html).

However, when I entered make command, a error occurs.I append a picture of error.

[image]

So, I searched Internet and found some information in here (www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/CRYPTO_lock.html).

I found information that CRYPTO_LOCK is 0x01, but I can't find defined CRYPTO_LCOK in /usr/local/openssl/crypto.h

So. I changed crypto.h to this (in below site) because this source have CRYPTO_LOCK (web.mit.edu/crypto/arch/sgi_65/include/openssl/crypto.h).

But, errors occurred more since it is not match other existing OpenSSL files.

So, I'm stuck in this problem.

Comment: Should be defined in `/usr/local/include/openssl/crypto.h`, if the installation prefix is `/usr/local`

Comment: Umm.. /usr/local/include/openssl/crypto.h exists but there is no definition of CRYPTO_LOCK

Comment: Then `grep` it: `grep --with-filename --color -R /usr/local/ /usr/include`. Check if the compiler accepts `-I/path/to/include/openssl/`.

Comment: I find /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h. What should I do now? Should I change MakeFile?

Comment: I change Makefile CFLAG = -g -02 -I/usr/include/openssl // openssl_CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/openssl but there is still same error.. :(